# Как создать ресурс файл C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, resources

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно создать ресурс файл например MyRes.resx еще один помимо основного Resources.resx и потом из этих двух файлов брать данные , например строковые?

Comment: Просто нажмите ПКМ - Добавить - Файл ресурса (.resx), далее в коде `ИмяФайла.ИмяСвойства`, готово.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!